# Visual studio cannot determine the type of my global variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio

What I have is :

```
    #include "thread.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    vector<Requester*> requesters; //global

    struct Requester {
       vector<thread> t;
       vector<int> tracks;
    };
```

Then in my function I have:

```
void serviceQ(){
  vector<Requester*> test = requesters; //error
}
```

The error is:

```
no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::vector<<error-type> *, std::allocator<<error-type> *>>" to "std::vector<Requester *, std::allocator<Requester *>>" exists
```

I'm very confused as to why this is. Why does it call my global variable an error type in the function? If I were to do something like:

```
void serviceQ(){
      vector<Requester*> test; 
      //do some stuff
      vector<Requester*> result = test; //no error
    }
```

Then there is no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define

```
vector<Requester*> requesters; //global
```

**after** the definition of `struct Requester`, as otherwise the compiler doesn't know what `Requester*` means when it attempts to define the corresponding `vector<Requester*>`. Alternatively, you can just declare

```
struct Requester;
```

above the line `vector<Requester*> requesters;`.

Comment: Wow, that was it. Thank you! I'm always forgetting the little things.

Comment: @user333121 No problem, glad it helps. Some compilers' error messages are not the most illuminating either. gcc for example is a bit better, and clearly states first: `error: 'Requester' was not declared in this scope`, so you can at least see that the error is related to an undefined type, and not to the vector.